# Android put text in html

Tags: android, html, webview

I got a html file like this:

```
<body>
    <h2>My html</h2>

    <p> You could save @value per year.</p>

</body>
```

I load this page in android with a WebView

I got a stored value that I need to replace with @value , is this possible?

Update PagerAdapterClass where i need to use it :

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        WebView Content;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container,
                false);
       Content= (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iaps_url);
     Content.loadUrl(myUrl.get(position));
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }
```

myUrl.get(position) reprezents the file location like "file:///android_asset/ScreenOne.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can use the Android JavaScript Bridge technique. Look at below steps.

Steps 1. For enabling the Java script in a web view by default the JavaScript is disabled. You can enable through the WebSettings attached to your webview then enable the javascript with `setJavaScriptEnabled()`

For example

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Steps 2. Building java script code to the android code

To bind the javascript and android code, it call addJavascriptInterface().passing it a class instance to bind to your JavaScript and an interface name that your JavaScript can call to access the class.
For example, you can include the following class in your Android application:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** call the stored value from java to javascript */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public integer getStoreValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You can bind this class to the JavaScript that runs in your WebView with addJavascriptInterface() and name the interface Android. For example:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

This creates an interface called Android for JavaScript running in the WebView. At this point, your web application has access to the WebAppInterface class. For example, here's some HTML and JavaScript that call the java stored value using the new interface when html widnow load: @[see this link](http://jsfiddle.net/xxwa7/)

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStoredValue() {
     var output = document.getElementById('values');
    output.innerHTML = Android.getStoreValue();

}
</script>
<body onload="getStoredValue()">
    <h2>My html</h2>

    <p> You could save <a id= 'values'>

        </a>  per year.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if you have any doubt, thank you.

Comment: what happen ? can you tell me

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

First read the HTML from assets/raw to a String. And then use the replaceAll function of the string.

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("webpage.html");
int size = is.available();

byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();

String page = new String(buffer);
page = page.replace("@value", "new string");

WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", page, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: i got   
Content= (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
 Content.loadUrl(myUrl); //myUrl is a string with its location 
Where do i need to apply this replace all ?

Comment: So your html is not a local file?